# print function not printing appropriate output using eval

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I am getting 2 different outputs using 2 similar commands:

```
>>> inp = 'print("hi")'
>>> print(eval(inp))
hi
None
>>> eval(inp)
hi
```

How to I make `print(eval(inp))` print just 'hi'? Why is None printing as well?

Comment: Because print returns `None`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Print returns whatever you give to it.

Comment: No, `print` returns `None`. You're confusing "printing" and "returning". `print` prints something to standard out and returns `None`. You don't need to print anything in a repl because Python prints the return value of each line automatically.

Comment: No, it does not. It **always returns `None`**. It *prints* the string representation of whatever you pass to it to the standard output. Printing and returning are two completely different things. Try `x = print("Foo"); print(x)` and see what happens

Comment: @SUPERMECHM500 Try this at the prompt `a=print(1); print(a is None)`

Comment: @ggorlen If I can't save the output of an eval operation, how do I save the most recent output to a variable as a string so I can print that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `print` is just a wrapper around `stdout`. In and of itself, it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here's what happens when you do `print(eval('print("hi")'))`:

1. `eval()` is called, with the argument `'print("hi")'`
2. Accordingly, the code `print("hi")` is executed
3. `"hi"` is printed to the console
4. Having finished executing, `print()` returns `None`.
5. Having executed the code `'print("hi")'`, the `eval()` function records the return call of that function. Which was `None`.
6. Accordingly, `eval()` returns `None`, since that was the result of the code it ran.
7. The outer `print()` call is supposed to print whatever the `eval()` function returned. Now it looks like `print(None)`.
8. `None` is printed to console.

tl;dr, `print()` is called two different times. Thus, two different things are printed: `"hi"` the first time, and `None` the second time.

---

If all you want is to print `"hi"`, you can just do `eval('print("hi")')` - or you could do `print(eval("hi"))`, since in this case `eval()` would return `"hi"` and that's what would be printed. In either of those cases you would only ever be executing one print statement.

Though, in general, *please do not use `eval()` for anything*. It's notoriously risky, prone to errors that can completely break your program, and there's nothing you can do with it that you can't do with the code you'd put inside it. The only feasible reason for using `eval()` would be to respond dynamically to user-generated code, which is a terrible idea because it allows code injections. The user shouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks! The purpose was to allow discord users to run python commands in a server. In which case, I am the only one who can do such a thing because it is blocked to anyone other than me who uses it.

Comment: The usual thing people do in that use case is define a specific set of legal commands (e.g. `calc`, `showimage`, `broadcast`, etc.) with defined parameters you can check. If you're absolutely set on using `eval()`, then there's probably a library out there somewhere that you can use (don't know one off the top of my head though) that would act as a code validator, making sure the effects aren't unreasonable.

Comment: I have some commands, I just wanted that to be developer only thing.